# how to increment row number when new row added?

Tags: jquery, jsp

i have a small table with a row which consists row number and file browser button and a text box and below that a link called add additional file,if you click on that link you can a same new empty row but my problem is i am not able to increment my row number. you can observe my functionality @   [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/6zT5W/
but that code now not using now my code looks like following.

**Jquery :**

```
function rowAdded(rowElement) {
    $(rowElement).find('input[type=text]').not('input[type=hidden]').val('');
        $(rowElement).find('input[type=file]').show();
        $(rowElement).find(".browsebutton1").removeClass("browsebutton1");
         var indexString = $(rowElement).html().split(']')[0];
        var index = indexString.substring(indexString.length-1, indexString.length);
        $("[name='ivrsFiles[" + index + "].fileName']").hide();
        $(rowElement).find('input[type=hidden]').val(0);
        $('input[type=file]').live('change', function() {
                var fileName=$(this).val();
                $(this).parent().addClass("newbrowse");

                $(this).parent().find('.description input').val(fileName.split('\\').pop());

        });
        isFormModified=true;

    }
```

**JSP :**

```
<body>
<table class="filetable" cellpadding='8' cellspacing='5'
                        id="listfiles">
 <c:forEach var="ivrsFile" items="${project.ivrsFiles}" varStatus="status">

   <tr class="filerowclass">
    <c:if   test="${fn:length(ivrsFile.fileName) > 0}">
        <td width='265px'  class="browsebutton1"><span class="browse-text">File <c:out value="${status.index+1}"></c:out>:</span>
          <form:hidden path="ivrsFiles[${status.index}].fileID"/>
        <input style="display:none" type="file"  name="ivrsFiles[${status.index}].file" />
        <span class="description " >
          <form:input path="ivrsFiles[${status.index}].fileName" readonly="true"/></span>
        </td>
        <td>Description:
          <form:input path="ivrsFiles[${status.index}].fileDescription" />
        </td>
        <td valign='middle'>
           <a  href="#"  class='delete-file'>Delete file</a>
        </td>

    </c:if> 

    <c:if test="${fn:length(ivrsFile.fileName) == 0}">
        <td width='265px'><span class="browse-text">File <c:out value="${status.index+1}"></c:out>:</span>
           <span class="browsebutton">  
                       <form:hidden path="ivrsFiles[${status.index}].fileID" value="0"/>
                      <input type="file" name="ivrsFiles[${status.index}].file" />  
                          <span class="description">  
                            <input name="ivrsFiles[${status.index}].fileName" type=text value="" ></input>  
                           </span>  
                    </span>
         </td>
         <td >Description:   
        <input type="text" name="ivrsFiles[${status.index}].fileDescription" />
             </td>
    <td valign='middle'>
    <a href="#" class='delete-file'>Delete file</a>     
    </td>                                       

    </c:if>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

But before executing that `rowAdded()` function i have an other js file which already adds a new row but with the last rows values and row number as it is in the previously existed list.Now i have changed the row here which becomes added just without any values in it,but i am not able to change the row number can any one help me.

Comment: Because while you are clicking add row button you are just cloning the previous line not creating the new row (according to your fiddle example).

Comment: then can you please write the code for me to create a new row instead of cloning

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zT5W/7/). This may help you,

```
function addRow() {
var table = document.getElementById("listfiles");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
//if(rowCount > 0){
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    row.id = "some_id"+rowCount;
    var newcell0 = row.insertCell(0);
    newcell0.innerHTML = "<td><input type='file' name='filename'></td>";
    var newcell1 = row.insertCell(1);
    newcell1.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' name='description' ><td>";
    var newcell2 = row.insertCell(2);
    newcell2.innerHTML = "<td><a onclick='deleteRow(this);'>Delete<a/><td>";
// }    
}

function deleteRow(ele){
    input_box = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");
    if (input_box == true) {
        $(ele).closest("tr").remove();
        return true;
    } else {
        // Output when Cancel is clicked
        return false;
    }
}
```

And your html may look like this,

```
<table id="listfiles">
</table> 
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow();">
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: you are not showing any row number beside the file label in the output

Comment: How do you want the output? For deleting you need only unique id.